# Define an empty container directly in a Haskell class?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

My task is to implement these functions but I'm stuck at first one.

Why can't I write `empty` like this ? (`ghci` complains : `couldn't match type`)

Am I not saying that `[]` should be of `type m k v` ?

```
class MapLike m where
    empty :: m k v
    empty = [] :: m k v
    lookup :: Ord k => k -> m k v -> Maybe v

newtype ListMap k v = ListMap { getListMap :: [(k,v)] } deriving (Eq,Show)
```

Comment: Yes, you're saying that, but `[]` is of type `[a]`. So the compiler is telling you that you're saying something that's wrong.

Comment: @sepp2k I thought that by writing empty = [] I give to this class some kind of 'default' implementation just like in a java interface.

Comment: @Oleg You are indeed correct; but the default implementation must match the most general type of the class function. With `DefaultSignatures`, you are allowed to give a default which is more specific than the most general type. However, that doesn't work for your case, because to have `[] :: m k v` you must have `m k ~ []`, but that's trivially false.

Comment: With `DefaultSignatures` (and `FlexibleContexts`) you could use something like `default empty :: Monoid (m k v) => m k v; empty = mempty`.

Comment: @user2407038 what is the significance of `~` in `m k ~ [] ` ?

Comment: `m k ~ []` means the type `m k` is equal to the type `[]` (the `~` symbol is the symbol used by GHC to denote a type equality in actual code; and it is useful to distinguish from value-level equality).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the root of your confusion may be the `class` keyword.

Forget all your preconceived notions of classes. A Haskell `class` is really nothing like a `class` in an object-oriented language like Java. Type classes are a lot more like a Java `interface` than a `class`.

More specifically, a `class` in Haskell defines a *signature*, or an *interface*, that a type may conform to. So when you write

```
class MapLike m where
    empty :: m k v
    lookup :: Ord k => k -> m k v -> Maybe v
```

you're declaring a class of map-like types `m :: * -> * -> *`, and in order to be `MapLike` a type must support at least the `empty` and `lookup` operations.

Now I can write functions which work for any `MapLike` type.

```
contains :: (MapLike m, Ord k) => m k v -> k -> Bool
m `contains` k =
    case lookup k m of
        Just _ -> True
        Nothing -> False
```

An *implementation* of a type class goes in an `instance`. You say which `class` you're implementing, you say which type implements it, and then you give an implementation for the functions declared in the class. So, below, I'm saying that `ListMap` is a `MapLike` type, and I'm explaining how the `empty` and `lookup` operations work for the `ListMap` type.

```
instance MapLike ListMap where
    empty = ListMap []
    lookup k (ListMap []) = Nothing
    lookup k (ListMap ((k', v):kvs)
        | k == k' = Just v
        | otherwise = lookup k (ListMap kvs)
```

Since `contains` works for any `MapLike` type, and `ListMap` is an instance of `MapLike`, we can use `contains` with a `ListMap`.

```
ghci> let myMap = ListMap [("foo", 'a'), ("bar", b)]
ghci> myMap `contains` "foo"
True
ghci> myMap `contains` "nabble"
False
```

Object-oriented classes classify objects, whereas type classes classify types. I do think the words `class` and `instance` are unfortunate - they're confusing to newcomers with an OO background - but Haskell predates OOP becoming popular so the language designers weren't to know. [Idris](https://www.idris-lang.org/), a newer language in the Haskell family, also has type classes, but [they're called `interface`s](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/interfaces.html), which I think is a much better name.

Comment: Thanks, indeed class and instances keywords are very confusing when coming from OOP